# Flat-File Authentication, login form does not shown - Shiny R Server Commercial Version v1.1.0.379

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny-server

I am evaluating [Shiny Server enterprise edition](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/pro/1.1.0/). I have a problem with authentication. The thing is that I enabled a Shiny Server with Flag-File authentication. Although when a client tries to access to a shiny app is not possible to see any login form in the web-page. As result the client can not access to the shiny app. Probably I am forgetting something related with the UI login form. The question is if I need to enable something for show the login form as in [this example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/personalized-ui.html). My shiny-server.conf file looks like this:

```
   # Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Specify the authentication method to be used.
# Initially, a flat-file database stored at the path below.
auth_passwd_file /etc/shiny-server/passwd;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 8000;
  # ssl /etc/shiny-server/key.pem /etc/shiny-server/cert.pem;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Only up tp 20 connections per Shiny process and at most 3 Shiny processes
    # per application. Proactively spawn a new process when our processes reach 
    # 90% capacity.
    utilization_scheduler 20 .9 3;
    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}

# Provide the admin interface on port 4151
admin 4151 {

  # Restrict the admin interface to the usernames listed here. Currently 
  # just one user named "admin"
  required_user admin;
}
```

I am trying to use the shiny app example provided [here](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/pro/1.1.0/) which code is [here](https://gist.github.com/trestletech/9790025).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error configuring my shiny-server.conf. I forgot to put the options: **required_user** and **required__group**.